# Some icons appear twice in the Sidebar

Tags: macos, finder, mobileme

I have two MacBooks and a Mac Mini that are synchronized through Mobile Me. All times they synchronize to Mobile Me, the MacBooks (which runs Mac OS X Lion) keep showing some icons two times, in the sidebar of the Finder; this doesn't happen to the Mac Mini, which runs Mac OS X Snow Leopard.

What can I do to avoid this, apart avoiding that the MacBooks running Mac OSX Lion synchronize with Mobile Me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because the applications are slightly different for each version of the OS so they are in effect 2 applications. Until you upgrade your mac mini I would recommend turning off syncing of just the dock.

Comment: This is interesting; the preference panel calls it "Docks Items," but I take from what you say that the option is not exactly referring only to the dock.